# Making Ajax request in portlets for liferay 6

Tags: ajax, jquery, liferay, liferay-6

I want to make an ajax call inside my jsp file which calls processAction method of a portlet, based on the success message from processAction method i need to make another call to serveResource method of portlet,please provide some examples..

Comment: You can find one example on [example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241861/ajax-in-liferay-portlet

Answer (score 10):

In portlets, processAction() methods are automatically followed by render method and hence ajax response will get embedded with HTML fragment generated by render method. So writing ajax in portlets is a bit tricky.

Have a look at this blog of mine.

http://ajax-and-portlets.blogspot.com/2011/09/ajax-best-practice-in-portlets.html

It gives an insight view of what's the best practice to implement ajax in portlets (for both JSR-168 and JSR-286 portlets).

In case you want sample portlets, you can contact me through the contact details from the blog. I'll be happy to help you.

Thanks
Jignesh

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228574/how-to-call-requestmapping-method-of-controller-having-specified-url-using-ajax) worked for me.

Basically, the Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW") // VIEW mapping (as opposed to EDIT)
public class MyPortlet {
    @RenderMapping
    public String handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
        return "defaultRender";
    }

    @ResourceMapping("myURL")
    public void handleMyResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
        OutputStream outStream;
        try {
            outStream = response.getPortletOutputStream();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.writeValue(outStream, "Hello world!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO : Do something with errors.
        }
    }
}
```

And the JSP:

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="myURL" var="myURL"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlink = "<%= myURL %>";
    $.ajax({
        url: urlink,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(jsondata) {
            console.log(jsondata);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> based on the success message from processAction method
>   That's not the right way to do it.
>   On calling portlet action URL in response you get usual render response, so you'll get page with all the portlets.
>   Instead you should use Portlet 2.0 resource serving feature, and return your response as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my portlet which has examples for both serveResource and processAction methods calling. 
[Ajax Jquery Portlet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxjqueryportl/files/)