# How to call @RequestMapping method of Controller having specified URL using AJAX

Tags: ajax, spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm very new to Spring and Portlet. I want to use jqgrid to show some list. I am trying to call a method in controller which is annoted with  the @RequestMapping but the method is not being called

My Controller has following method

```
@Controller(value = "myController")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/myURL",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody MyDTO  initItemSearchGrid(RenderResponse response, RenderRequest request){
        MyDTO myDto=new MyDTO();
        return myDto;
    }
}
```

My JSP code using AJAX

```
var urlink="/myURL"; /* myURL is the exact String written in value Attribute of
                              resourceMapping in Controller*/
$.ajax({
    url :urlink,
    cache: false,
    data:$('#myForm').formSerialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(jsondata){
       ...
    }
});
```

When above AJAX code is executing my method is not called.

Comment: what's in the logs? What's the response code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention Portlets in your question. Working with Spring and portlets is a bit different from servlets.

So, assuming you have a portlet like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW") // VIEW mapping (as opposed to EDIT)
public class MyPortlet {
    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
        ResourceURL resourceUrl = response.createResourceURL();
        resourceUrl.setResourceID("myResource"); // this is the id used to reference a @ResourceMapping
        ModelAndView ret = new ModelAndView("myPortlet");
        ret.addObject("resourceUrl", resourceUrl.toString());
        return ret;
    }

    @ResourceMapping("myResource")
    public void handleMyResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
        OutputStream out = response.getPortletOutputStream();
        // write whatever to output
    }
}
```

As you can see, the @ResourceMapping is identified by a resource ID. The url for the resource mapping can be created using the standard portlet API methods and classes `createResourceURL()` and `javax.portlet.ResourceURL`.

If you prefer to use the portlet taglibrary instead, you can also generate a resource URL using the `<portlet:resourceRequest>` tag.

Your view might look something like this

**myPortlet.jsp**

```
...
<script>
$.ajax({
         url :${resourceUrl},
             cache: false,
             data:$('#myForm').formSerialize(),
             dataType: "json",
             type: "GET",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function(jsondata){
        .........   
        .........
        .........
         }
        });
</script>
...
```