# Ajax in liferay portlet

Tags: ajax, liferay

I have created one portlet in liferay(This is my first portlet). In that i have followed mvc structure of liferay. 
Java file for it as follows:-

```
package com.liferay.samples;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.PortletPreferences;
//import javax.portlet.GenericPortlet;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

public class MyGreetingPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @Override
    public void processAction(
            ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

       PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();

        String greetingname = actionRequest.getParameter("greetingname");
        String greeting     = actionRequest.getParameter("greeting");

        if (greeting != null && greetingname != null) 
        {    

            prefs.setValue(greetingname, greeting);
            prefs.store();
         }
        //System.out.println("In doView code");
        super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }
     public void fetchdataAction( ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {  
        System.out.println("In doView code");
        //super.fetchdataAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);

    }

}
```

But when i call fetchdataAction() using ajax from view.jsp file it returns nothing.
view.jsp file as follows :-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<div id="ContentGreeting">
This is the <b>Thired Test</b> portlet.
<%


    PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
//forEachPreference
    //String em[]            = String[2];
    //em                     = prefs.getValues();
    Enumeration em          =   prefs.getNames();
    //ArrayList aList = Collections.list(em);
    //out.println("value :-"+ aList.get(1));
    String[] greeting           =   new String[3];
    int i=0;
    while(em.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String key = (String)em.nextElement();
        greeting[i] = (String)prefs.getValue(

         key, "Hello! Welcome to our portal.");
        //out.println("<br> value :"+greeting);


%>
<p id='id<%= i %>'  onclick="ajaxcallTofetchpage();"><%= greeting[i] %></p>
<portlet:renderURL var="editGreetingURL">

    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%= editGreetingURL %>&greetingname=<%= key %>">Edit greeting</a>

<%
    i++;
    }
%> 
</div>
<portlet:renderURL var="addGreetingURL">

    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/add.jsp" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<p><a href="<%= addGreetingURL %>">Add greeting</a></p>
<portlet:resourceURL var="fetchdataAction">

    <portlet:param name="fetchdataAction" value="/view.jsp" />

</portlet:resourceURL>

<script>
    //$("#id1").hide("slow");
    function ajaxcallTofetchpage()
    {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<%= fetchdataAction %>",
           data: "name=John",
           success: function(msg){


            alert(msg);

           }
         });
    }
</script>
```

If you are able to help me that will be great help for me.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of creating a `fetchDataAction( ActionRequest request, ...)` method, you need to override `serveResource( ResourceRequest request, ...)`.

```
public void serveResource( ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    String jspPage = resourceRequest.getParameter("fetchDataAction");
            if (jspPage != null) {
        include(jspPage, request, response, PortletRequest.RESOURCE_PHASE);
    }
    else {
        super.serveResource(request, response);
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Stackfish, 

I wish to do the same kind of thing but in different way. I am having 2 Portlets. 1) For Search and 2) For Displaying the Search Result.. I am done successfully with that without AJAX call. Now i want to use the Ajax. Can you please guide me how can I achieve this? I am using Inter Portlet Communication(IPC) mechanism for this. Kindly guide me to achieve this. I am struggling in this for so long....Thanks